# JavaScript - how can I create a function which can remove numbers from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, while-loop

I've tried this

```js
function removeFromArray(manyMoreArgs, number) {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < manyMoreArgs.length) {
    if (manyMoreArgs[i] === number) {
      manyMoreArgs.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  return manyMoreArgs;
}
console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)); // result = [1, 2, 4] this removes 3 from array. it works! but then >>
console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2)); // result = [1, 2, 4] this removes 3 from array too but I also want to remove 2 from array
```

What should I do if I want to remove numbers from array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either define your `numbers` parameter as an array

```js
function removeFromArray(manyMoreArgs, numbers) {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < manyMoreArgs.length) {
    if (numbers.includes(manyMoreArgs[i])) {
      manyMoreArgs.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  return manyMoreArgs;    
}

console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], [3]));// result = [1, 2, 4] this removes 3 from array. it works! but then >>
console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 2]));// result = [1, 2, 4] this removes 3 from array too but I also want to remove 2 from array
```

or as a [variadic argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

```js
function removeFromArray(manyMoreArgs, ...numbers) {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < manyMoreArgs.length) {
    if (numbers.includes(manyMoreArgs[i])) {
      manyMoreArgs.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  return manyMoreArgs;    
}

console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3));// result = [1, 2, 4] this removes 3 from array. it works! but then >>
console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2));// result = [1, 2, 4] this removes 3 from array too but I also want to remove 2 from array
```

Comment: oh big thanks, it works now! I have to take a look what .include is.
(i'm a beginner, I've never seen this syntax before)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: If it works, feel free to accept the answer ...

Comment: I click the ✔ it turns green
then it turns back to grey again automatically
did I miss something?

Comment: because you accepted another answer ...

Comment: oh okay, one at a time
appreciate your time. non I accepted you answer
thank you again

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make use of a JavaScript function that takes in these two arrays and filters the first to contain only those elements that are not present in the second array. And then return the filtered array.

```
    const removeNum = (arr,...numbers) =>{
       const arr2 = [...numbers]
       console.log(arr2); 
       numbers = arr.filter(el => {
          return arr2.indexOf(el) === -1;
        });;
       console.log(numbers);   
    }

removeNum([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2)
```

Comment: thank you, today I learn new things (.filter/.include)
you gave me new perspective